# javascript function in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have some little code that I can't get to work. Here it is:

```
<input type='password' name='Confirmpwd' id='Confirmpwd'
       onkeyup="if(this.value != '') myFunction('checkConfirmpwd', (Password.value == this.value) ? 1 : 0;, this.id);" />
```

I'm 100% sure that `Password.value` and `this.value` are correct when I place them in there. So it's not a problem with the variables.

The problem is that, `myFunction` isn;t executed anymore when I try to compare `Password.value` and `this.value` in the argument like above. `myFunction` is declared like this:

```
myFunction(val1, val2, val3) { ...some code... }
```

What my goal is that I can compare the 2 strings and send them to `myFunction` when I call the function.

Comment: You seem to have an extra semicolon after the 0 in the second argument of the call to `myFunction`. That may just be a typo in your post here, but if it's in the original code, it would cause the call to fail with a syntax error.

Comment: Provide JSFiddle please. What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `;` indicates an end of statement.  If there are missing parameter or brackets that have not been closed when a semi-colon is encountered, it may result in an error.

This is the case in this instance.

Change the code to something like

```
if(this.value != '') myFunction('checkConfirmpwd', (Password.value == this.value) ? 1 : 0, this.id);
```

Comment: Except for command languages like Tcl or bash, most languages don't really have the concept of "command". It's the end of a **statement**.

Comment: @slebetman : see - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#Conditional_Statements.  Although I understand the confusion and have reworded it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the onkeyup in an external javascript file rather than the same HTML file. It's better to do this for ease-of-editing and performance:

HTML

```
<input type="password" name="Confirmpwd" id="Confirmpwd" />
```

JS

```
document.getElementById("Confirmpwd").onkeyup = function () {
    "use strict";
    if (this.value !== "") { // !== is better than !=
        myFunction("checkConfirmpwd", (Password.value === this.value) ? 1 : 0, this.id); // === is better than ==
    }
};
```

And all we did there was change `;,` to `,`. It was just a typo

Comment: It's a good idea to put the code in a function that's parsed when the JS is loaded, but how does it improve security?

Comment: Imo putting it in the `onkeyup` part will hide the script, right? -> More security?

Comment: @TedHopp Since you can "sandbox" the external script (wrap it in `(function { // code }())`) to avoid other scripts overwriting functions which you've used in an `on<something>` attribute.

Comment: @TedHopp @Krowi No, actually, because with debugging tools you can simply pause the javascript, then `onkeyup` the input and the debugger will show you where the code is. It's so hackers can't overwrite your functions as easily.

Comment: Hackers can simply assign a different `onkeyup` property to intercept the call and do whatever they want (including tracing into the original code to see what it does). There's no real increase in security here.

Comment: @TedHopp I dunno, I just thought I read it somewhere, but I can't find anything to suggest it's more secure now. Anyway, most people would say external is better. I'll edit the question to reflect that